# Paypal Standard - Add to cart button (with options) Can i use a text link instead of button image and remain secure?

Tags: button, text, paypal, standards, cart

Im using Paypal Standard shopping cart - Add to cart button (with options)

Can i use a text link instead of the Paypal provided button image while the button code is still securely hosted on paypal ?

I want to use a text link and style the button that way instead of the standard add to cart buttons.

I see in Paypal button generator that you can make a text link for email, but that doesnt work for add to cart buttons with options, which is sometimes necessary.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you check "Save button at PayPal" option , your buttons are hosted and secured by PayPal.

Unfortunately, any button with "drop-down" options generated via Paypal button generator will not have the email tab generated. This is because it is highly impossible to have drop-down options in an email link.This is intended behavior.

To use a link for add to cart which is non-hosted : 
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_cart&business=S4X5XW328WAYY&item_name=tests&currency_code=USD&amount=10.00&add=1

where `business` is your paypal account email address or business ID.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vimal, yes ok i understand about that.

Is there a way to manually modify the paypal generated code(with options) so i can have a text link for 'Add to Cart' without the standard paypal button images?

Then i can style the text link via css to suit my websites design.